# How to turn matrix into tuple?

Tags: dolphindb

How can I convert a double matrix into a tuple, do I have to construct an empty tuple first, and then use a loop to add each column of the matrix ? Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

First convert the matrix into a table, and then table.values() can be directly converted into tuple data

```py
m=matrix(1..5, 11..15)
k=table(m)
k.values()
typestr(k.values())
```

Result is ANY VECTOR, which means each column convert to a tuple.